# How to a share link in twitter with out set up in iphone settings page?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter, social-framework

i want to share a link in twitter. At the time click on twitter button share a link.But first time click on twitter button i want to show  twitter login to share in that page only no need to go in iphone settings page

[image]

My code is

```
UIButton *twitterBtn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,100, 50,  50)];   
[twitterBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Twitter-icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[twitterBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(twitterBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:twitterBtn];

-(void)twitterBtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *link=@"http://myWebpage.com";
    TWTRComposer *composer = [[TWTRComposer alloc] init];
    [composer setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@ ....",      [itemDetailsDict objectForKey:@"name"],link]];

    [composer setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fabric"]];
    [composer showWithCompletion:^(TWTRComposerResult result) {

        if (result == TWTRComposerResultCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"Tweet composition cancelled");
        }

        else {
            NSLog(@"Sending Tweet!");
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: can u use SLComposeViewController and try

Comment: but it navigating to settings page i want to show the login twitter page on their only no need to navigate alert

Comment: If you want to use the Social framework classes, the user must log in using their Twitter account in the settings, if you don't want this, you should use Twitter API for iOS https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios

Comment: i used  dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios this link but i got the popup authrize app like that when cancel the popup again  background showing above i mentioned screen

Comment: I'm getting same issue ,did u get any solution for this @iOS_Ramesh

Comment: i did little bit changes in my code so first time it shows app Authorize popup  login into twitter after user logged out twitter in device  settings so next time onwards i am showing above alert only.